# Cannot GET /mentor/mypage/pre-ordered_Lectures/1

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

i'm not really good at English and beginner of coding. i use javascript and my OS is Mac.
Anyway, i wrote row query in MysqlWorkbench and now, i want to write it in VScode to sequelize.

```
select reservation_datetime
from LectureReservation
Inner Join Lecture
On LectureReservation.lecture_id = Lecture.id
Where Lecture.mentor_id = 1
```

this is my query and

```
module.exports = {
    get: (req, res) => {
        if (req.params.id) {
            LectureReservation
            .findOne({
                include: [
                    {
                        model: Lecture,
                        where: {
                            Lecture_id: Lecture.id,
                        },
                    },
                ],
                attributes: ['reservation_datetime'],
                where: {
                    mentor_id: req.params.id,
                },
            })
            .then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    res.status(200).json({ message: 'OK!' });
                } else {
                    res.status(409).json({ message: 'Wrong Access' });
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            });
        }
    },
};
```

this is my sequelize code. and
[image]

this is my err code in postman..

Result: How can I edit my sequelize code to fix my postman err..?

Comment: post your route snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is not a sequelize related error. The error code is 404. Which means the route is not available. Please check your routes.

Also you don't need to specify the include condition if your sequelize models associated properly. You can just write

```
include: [
    {
        model: Lecture
    },
],
```